# regex basics: preg_match() value with asterisks

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this regex:

```
preg_match("/(comment|vid|nice)/i", $id)
```

And I want `vid` part to match with `video` or `ivideo`.

What's the right way to add asterisks in `vid` so it matches with those terms?

Comment: `[^\s]*vid[^\s]*` or `[\w-]*vid[\w-]*` should work...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\p{L}*` where `\p{L}` matches any lower- and uppercase letters and `*` is a quantifier matching zero or more occurrences:

```
(comment|\p{L}*vid\p{L}*|nice)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fP9jO0/1) and [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/JOCike):

```
$re = '/(comment|\p{L}*vid\p{L}*|nice)/';
$s = "new ivideo";
if (preg_match($re, $s, $m)) {
    echo $m[0];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. To confirm, will this match with the following example term: **video-player-5681ad0a08875**

Comment: It depends on what you need to get. The [match will be found](https://regex101.com/r/fP9jO0/2).

Comment: If you have any more questions regarding this (like Unicode support, matching `comment` and `nice` only as whole words) please feel free to drop a comment. Note that you can just match non-whitespaces around `vid` with `\S*`: [`(comment|\S*vid\S*|nice)`](https://regex101.com/r/fP9jO0/3).

Comment: Please let me know if this works for you or if you need more assistance with it.

Answer (score 0):

Surely there are many options for this, but one that comes to mind is

```
preg_match("/(comment|[\w-]*vid[\w-]*|nice)/i", $id)
```

whereas

1. `\w` matches `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9` and `_`
2. `-` simply matches `-`
3. `[...]` is a character class, so it matches both 1. and 2.
4. `*` means matching 0 or more times

Btw you can fiddle with the matches by simply using an online tester like http://www.regextester.com.

Comment: Thanks! To confirm, will this match with the following example term: **video-player-5681ad0a08875**

Comment: @GaryWoods I think so, yes. See my edited answer, i added support for the `-` character.

Comment: The `\w` also includes underscore. Your original answer would have also worked without the `-` support; there are no anchors so just needs to find a match on that part.

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
preg_match("/(comment|i?vid|nice)/i", $id)
```

The `?` makes the preceding `i` optional.

Regex 101 demo: https://regex101.com/r/tK2iK2/1

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/494456

```
if(preg_match("/(comment|i?vid|nice)/i", 'video-player-5681ad0a08875')) {
     echo 'It is a match';
} else {
     echo  'It is not a match';
}
```

Comment: Cheers. To confirm, will this match with the following example term: **video-player-5681ad0a08875**

Comment: Yes, see demo here https://regex101.com/r/tK2iK2/2, you could have it be stricter though.. Added PHP demo to answer as well.

Comment: That string would have been found with your first regex though, no? Maybe update your question because I don't think you've phrased what you are after.. https://eval.in/494458 (your original regex)

Comment: @GaryWoods question here? updating your question?